# Web API: Pass Date Time in URL (Format)

Tags: date, time, format, asp.net-web-api

I am using microsoft's web api for a REST API implementation.

I want to pass a date/time value and choose the ISO 8601 format.
In my requests I handle the "where clause" (to specify the wanted ressources) in the query-string.
In this filter-clauses I handle comparison with strings numbers and the date time in the **ISO 8601** format.

strings are enclosed with '

> for example: 'this is a string'

numbers are only digits/decimal point:

> for example 123 or 12.34

and currently is specify date times like this:

> date'2007-12-24T18:21Z'

Is there a better way to say: "this is a date, not a string"?
I search standardized enclosing characters for date time values.

Comment: don't get what you say, could you show sample urls?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you calling your service like this http://someservice.com/resource/1346168537681/otherparam

I would do something like this
 - Get time in milliseconds
 - Decode parameters, for date you could simply check for length or go more robust if you like

Comment: This would not work because this params will be passed in the query-string and it is not static defined if I pass a date or a string to the key. (It is dynamically and need aspecial format to say: "handle this a string as a date".